# Error: must include rest_framework.authtoken in INSTALLED_APPS or set TOKEN_MODEL to None

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a problem with the rest_framework_simplejwt package. I installed it and configured everything.
and I am encountering an error.
django.core.exceptions. ImproperlyConfigured: You must include rest_framework.authtoken in INSTALLED_APPS or set TOKEN_MODEL to None.

this is my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

REST_AUTH_TOKEN_MODEL = None

REST_USE_JWT = True

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=5),
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is your entire `settings.py`. If you look around, you'll spot a variable named `INSTALLED_APPS`. There you can add your `rest_framework.authtoken`

Comment: whole point is rest_framework.authtoken is builtin and i want to replace it with simplejwt but it still looks for this rest_framework.authtoken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me just downgrading dj_rest_auth to 2.2.8 version worked.
looks like newer versions need different approach

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), add `rest_framework_simplejwt` to the installed apps.
I highly recommend you read the docs from the link that I posted it will take you step by step